# How to not create a new Account in convertLead()

Tags: account, lead-conversion, merge

I developing an app, which convert all `Leads` to `Contacts`, but it always create a new `Account`.

How can I code a method which validates if the `Company Name` is the same than any existing `Account.Name`, then convert the `Lead`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you'll want to determine a 'key' field that uniquely identifies an account, then query for accounts with a matching key value and generate a map. Then as you're iterating over your leads to convert and creating your `List<Database.LeadConvert>` you can use the `setAccountId` method to convert that lead into a pre-existing account. If you're using Account Name, your code would look something like this. Note, however that this will only work for an exact match. If you need to use fuzzy logic, this gets much more complicated.

```
List<Lead> leadsToConvert = [Select Id, Company From Lead]; //modify your query as needed

//Generate set of unique key values
Set<String> accNames = new Set<String>();
for(Lead l : leadsToConvert){
    accNames.add(l.Company);
}

//Create your map using Name as the key
Map<String,Account> accMap = new Map<String,Account>();
for(Account a : [Select Id, Name From Account Where Name = :accNames]){
    accMap.put(a.Name,a);
}

//Assemble List<Database.LeadConvert>
List<Database.LeadConvert> leadConverts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
for(Lead l : leadsToConvert){
    Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
    lc.setLeadId(l.Id);
    //if there is an existing account with the same name
    //convert the lead into that account by grabbing the
    //id from the map above
    if(accMap.containsKey(l.Company)){
        lc.setAccountId(accMap.get(l.Company).Id);
    }
    //set other values
    leadConverts.add(lc);
}
//do other processing
```

Alternatively, you could not specify a List for your leadsToConvert and simply modify the initial `for` loop like this.

```
//Generate set of unique key values
Set<String> accNames = new Set<String>();
for(Lead l : [Select Id, Company From Lead]){
    accNames.add(l.Company);
}
```

Comment: What kind of variable is 'leadsToConvert', I'm trying to understand the syntax. At loading the class this error is shown Variable does not exist: leadsToConvert

Comment: I'm using this leadsToConvert = [SELECT id, Company from Lead]; but there is no succeed?

Comment: I have edited my answer for clarification.

Comment: Todd -- there may be some case sensitivity issues here, the map `accmap` has case sensitive keys but the SOQL query to find Accounts is case insensitive except for unique fields, and account name isn't a unique field - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm?search_text=sensitive . So lead company `foo` will find Account `Foo` but the `containsKey(l.company)` will be false

Comment: Excellent point on the case-sensitivity, and I hadn't thought of that for the purposes of this answer. I was thinking more the distinction between Acme/Acme Corp/Acme Inc. but for that, and other reasons, we actually use domain to match to existing accounts. It's also not perfect, but I've found it to be generally accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Standard SalesForce Convert button already does that. Dont go custom code route, simply use this button and if the existing company name matches then it gives two options on the convert page. Create a New Account and Use the existing Account which matches.